# Discord.js code works fine while playing local files, while trying to play urls it doesn't play anything

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, voice

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents:

  [

      GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,

      GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,

      GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,

]

});

const config =  require('./config.json');

const { joinVoiceChannel, createAudioPlayer, NoSubscriberBehavior, createAudioResource, AudioPlayerStatus, VoiceConnectionStatus, StreamType } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const { join } = require('path');

client.once('ready', async() => {

    console.log("connected");

    const channels = client.guilds.cache.find(f => f.name==="<my-guild>").channels;

  let channel= channels.cache.find(r => r.name === "General");

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({

channelId: channel.id,

guildId: channel.guildId,

adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,

});                                                                                                                                         console.log("joined voice channel");

const player = createAudioPlayer();

let resource = createAudioResource("https://streams.ilovemusic.de/iloveradio2.mp3", { inlineVolume: true,

  inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary});

resource.volume.setVolume(1)

connection.subscribe(player);

player.play(resource);

});

client.login(config.token);
```

It worked fine last month, Trying to run it this month and nothing is heard via stream, but local audio files work fine.

Expectation: Url should play as discord createAudioResource supports urls.

The main problem is local files play, while remote urls don't. There's no error though so I am confused on how to debug it.

Comment: is the remote url provided in your code the actual one, or just an example? because it's giving 404: https://streams.ilovemusic.de/iloveradio2.mp3

Comment: The domain performs a re-direct at that link, so your API usage is in question. To debug, check your network in debug mode and see what the request is sending back and handle the error properly. When you're hoisting other websites on yours you can run into a dependency issue where they could cut you off and you must cope.

Comment: @GrafiCode The link loads fine on chrome, (it's a live stream of radio)

Comment: `HTTP ERROR 404` I get this error on that URL

Comment: The url works though, there should be problem on your end, my question is solved btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should a problem of ffmpeg installation, tried running the script on a new machine (after installing ffmpeg) and it works fine.